# liberty doesn't log the remote/front-end user IP in the access log

Tags: websphere-liberty

Our deployment Apache Httpd(WAS Plugin) + WLP cluster, the access log of Apache Httpd shows the correct front-end user IP, but in the access log of WLP, the IP of HTTP request is the Apache Httpd server IP instead of front-end user IP.

I turned on the WAS WebServer Plug-in DEBUG log level, and saw $WSRA was set correctly in http_plugin.log as follows:

```
[24/Nov/2016:02:42:13.63592] 00001a55 9e5f6700 - DETAIL: mod_was_ap24_http: cb_get_headers: Skipping header name '$WSRA'; This is a restricted WebSphere header
7483 [24/Nov/2016:02:42:13.63594] 00001a55 9e5f6700 - DEBUG: Set header |$WSAT| to |openid-connect|
7484 [24/Nov/2016:02:42:13.63596] 00001a55 9e5f6700 - DEBUG: Set header |$WSIS| to |true|
7485 [24/Nov/2016:02:42:13.63598] 00001a55 9e5f6700 - DEBUG: Set header |$WSSC| to |https|
7486 [24/Nov/2016:02:42:13.63600] 00001a55 9e5f6700 - DEBUG: Set header |$WSPR| to |HTTP/1.1|
7487 [24/Nov/2016:02:42:13.63602] 00001a55 9e5f6700 - DEBUG: Set header |$WSRA| to |9.125.233.196|
7488 [24/Nov/2016:02:42:13.63604] 00001a55 9e5f6700 - DEBUG: Set header |$WSRH| to |9.125.233.196|
7489 [24/Nov/2016:02:42:13.63606] 00001a55 9e5f6700 - DEBUG: Set header |$WSRU| to xxxxxx
7490 [24/Nov/2016:02:42:13.63608] 00001a55 9e5f6700 - DEBUG: Set header |$WSSN| to |9.115.114.76|
7491 [24/Nov/2016:02:42:13.63610] 00001a55 9e5f6700 - DEBUG: Set header |$WSSP| to |443|
```

Meanwhile in the backend WLP server, I have a JSP to print out the HTTP headers, $WSRA is still correct.

But in WLP access.log, something was wrong, it used the proxy server IP(which is same to $WSSN) instead of $WSRA.

```
9.115.114.76 xxxxxxx "GET /test/ HTTP/1.1" ...
```

We would like to log $WSRA the real remote user IP in the access.log. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to use a custom WAS access log format " **%{WSRA}i** %u %{t}W "%r" %s %b " to print the real remote user IP address to the access log